# combine multiple png to a single transparent png using PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a lot of small pngs which I want to combine them to a single png file, I use python to do the job, this is my code:

```
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw  
import os,math

def combine_images(path,out,padding=1):
    imgs=[]
    min_width,max_width,min_height,max_height=-1,-1,-1,-1
    for infile in os.listdir(path):
        f,ext=os.path.splitext(infile)
        if ext== ".png":
            im=Image.open(os.path.join(path,infile))
            imgs.append(im)
            min_width = im.size[0] if min_width<0 else  min(min_width,im.size[0])
            max_width = im.size[0] if max_width<0 else  max(max_width,im.size[0])
            min_height = im.size[1] if min_height<0 else  min(min_height,im.size[0])
            max_height = im.size[1] if max_height<0 else  max(max_height,im.size[0])
    #calculate the column and rows
    num = len(imgs)
    column_f = math.ceil(math.sqrt(num))
    row_f = math.ceil(num / column_f)

    column = int(column_f)
    row = int(row_f)

    #out image
    box=(max_width + padding*2,max_height + padding*2)
    out_width = row * box[0]
    out_height = column * box[1]

    //out_image=Image.new('L', (out_width,out_height), color=transparent)
    out_image=Image.new("RGB", (out_width, out_height))
    for y in range(row):
        for x in range(column):
            index = (y * column) + x
            if index < num:
                out_image.paste(imgs[index],(x * box[0],y * box[1]))
    out_image.save(out)

combine_images('icon','t.png')
```

The logic is simple, read the pngs in a certain dir, , calculate the number,size of the images,then create a new image and paste them one by one. Extra calculate are used to make the result image as square as possible.

However this is what I got:http://pbrd.co/1kzErSc

I meet two problems:

1 I can not make the out image transparent.

2 It seems that my layout of the icons will waste too many space in the image.

I wonder if it is possible to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
out_image=Image.new("RGB", (out_width, out_height))
```

You need to specify that you want an alpha channel when creating the out image

```
out_image=Image.new("RGBA", (out_width, out_height))
```

With regards to the wasted space, two things come to mind:

1. Does it matter? If you only care about file size (not image size) check if the image actually increased in file size. As PNG is a compressed format, so it may not matter.
2. Sort the images by height after loading them, group them into similar height images and change the grid size for each group. This may not work though if the application using the images has to guess the size of each icon.